# Length in different lists

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have two list with the next content:

```
l1 = ((at1) (at2))
```

and

```
l2 = (((at11) (at21))((at12) (at22)))
```

with `l2` created from `l1`.

The problem is: I consider `l1` like an instance of a problem, so `l2` will be two instances of the same problem but, when I used (length l1), the result is 2, which isn't correct for this approach.
I've tried to do (list l1), which result in (length l1) = 1, but this  carry that my function doesn't create well `l2`.

I've tried to use this code, but, with these two lists, it doesn't work fine. With it, `l2`could create another list `l3`, but `l1` can't create `l2`. The code would be:

```
(define (applyfunc l1)
  (let ((l2 '()))
    (cond ((not(null? l1))
              (for/list ([i (length l1)])
                (set! l2 (append l2 (func l1))) 
                )
              )
          )
    l2)
)
```

`(applyfunc ((at1) (at2))...)` should return a specialization of the atributes at1 and at2, ie, `l2`. But, with the code above, it doesnt' work, because it takes `l1 = ((at1) (at2))` like two pieces, (length l1 = 2) and not like an instance. If I take `l2`, it contains 2 instances, so, the result would be `l3`, with 2 atributes especialization for each one, ie, a list like `l2` with 4 instances and 2 atributes each one. The problem is that, when `l1`enters, it considers `(at1)` and `(at2)`, but no `((at1)(at2))` How can I do it? Thanks for help!

Comment: What result do you want?  `l1` is a template, `l2` has two templates so result is '2'?

Comment: @GoZoner I need that the length of `l1` will be 1 instead of 2, and the length of `l2` will still be 2. Then I can take `l1`as an instance, and `l2` as two instances for a function like the explain up here.

Answer (score 0):

```
(cond (not (null? l1) ...))
```

This form will evaluate `not` which turns out to be the procedure `#<procedure:not>` and since everything but `#f` is true it will start evaluating the rest of the chain starting with `(null? l1)`..

You have no examples of how it is suppose to work so I leave it at that. For Scheme this is far too imperative.

Comment: I've added the ( that was missing. Sorry about that. About how it's suppose to work, it's difficult to explain, but the problem is the considered down the explanation. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @PedroL. An example usage like what `(applyfunc '(((at11) (at21))((at12) (at22))))` and `(applyfunc '((at1) (at2))))` are to return. Right now I know you are suppose to append the result of `func` on an element, like  `((at11) (at21))` or `(at11)`, but func is not defined so for me it's not obvious what needs to be done at all. Right now you question seem like an ill defined [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Ok.`(applyfunc ((at1) (at2))` should return an especialization of the atributes at1 and at2, ie, `l2`. But, with the code above, it doesnt' work, because it takes `l1 = ((at1) (at2))` like two pieces, (length l1 = 2) and not like an instance. If I take `l2`, it contains 2 instances, so, the result would be `l3`, with 2 atributes especialization for each one, ie, a list like `l2` with 4 instances and 2 atributes each one.

(I put this explanation in the main post as well. Thank you again.)

Comment: @PedroL. Perhaps you should [flatten](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=flatten#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._flatten%29%29) the list to get a count of atoms.